# Sending one mail for each recipient

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm trying to send the same mail to each recipient, I've been trying to loop through the list but it only sends to all of recipients in a group mail lot of times.

I would like to know how can I send the same mail for each recipient without having sending to all of them in one mail directly

```
msg = MIMEText(HTML_CONTENT, 'html')
msg['Subject'] = 'some subject'
msg['From'] = email

sendTo = [
    "somemail@mail.com",
    "another@mail.com",
    "ok@kkk.com"
]

msg['To'] = ", ".join(sendTo)

conn = SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
try:
    conn.starttls()
    conn.set_debuglevel(False)
    conn.login(email, password)

    i = 0
    for i in range(len(sendTo)):
        conn.sendmail(email, sendTo[i], msg.as_string())
        i += 1
finally:
    conn.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the problem, but I believe that a problem in your code where there is `i += 1` - if you are iterating over the range of a number (length in your case), it will automatically iterate over the next item so you adding this line of code will make it actually iterate two at a time.

Comment: It still sends a group e-mail

Comment: try removing this line: msg['To'] = ", ".join(sendTo)

Comment: Yes, like I said I was not sure if it was the problem, I was just informing the OP of a problem.

Comment: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Comment: Oh sorry I did not mean to post that.

Comment: OH SO SORRY I DID NOT MEAN TO POST THAT.

Comment: oh so sorry i didnt realise caps was on